# Connecting 4-20mA signal to esp8266 ADC circuit

Tags: analog, adc, esp8266

I'm trying to measure a 4-20mA signal using an ESP8266. I designed this circuit to scale the 4-20mA signal to 200mv-1V signal suitable for ESP8266 ADC. Is this circuit a good practice? Should I add or remove any part?
[image]

Comment: I am looking for the precision 50\$\Omega\$ resistor across which the 20 mA current will drop 1V. Instead I see potentiometers. That is fine, but you will obviously need to adjust your  pots to get the voltage signal you want.

Comment: I don't if it is true or not but I thought if I put just a 50R resistor then for 4ma the loop voltage goes down to 200mv which may lower the noise immunity. Is there any standard for the lowest value we can pick for loop resistance?

Comment: The standard loop resistance for 4-20 mA is 250\$\Omega\$, which gives a 1-5V output. As far as I know, there is no standard lowest value.

Answer (score 3):

A major drawback of your approach is that it requires calibration. Unless the potentiometers are set correctly, your output will not be correct according to the formula that gives

- 1 V output for 20 mA input
- 200 mV output for 4 mA input

An alternative approach, that does not require calibration is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXiR2r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course the accuracy of the circuit will depend upon the accuracy of the resistor, and the the offset voltages of the op-amp. If these do not give you sufficient accuracy, then a circuit that requires calibration may be your best option. However, calibrating from within your micro-controller, as opposed to using potentiometers, is an option you should consider.

---

Addendum:

> Is there any standard for the lowest value we can pick for loop resistance?

I am not sure that this would be necessary, but if one of your objectives is to ensure that the current loop has at least 250\$\Omega\$ load, the following will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foeYEl.png)</sup>

Comment: what's the purpose of the op-amp?

Comment: what I means is I don't think it helps the ESP ADC is several megaohms,.

Comment: The op-amp is a voltage follower. It has high input impedance to prevent loading in parallel with the precision 50 \$\Omega\$ resistor. It may be omitted if the circuit using the 0.2-1V signal does not draw current.

Comment: the ESP8266 ADC has several megaohms input impedance. it's a 10 bit ADC, so its noit going to distort the measurement of a 50 ohm source enough to have any effect.

Comment: Then the op-amp is not required.